# I'm unable to find data source in ODBC(RDO) to add in Crystal reporting Mysql using VS2015

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports, odbc, mysql-odbc-connector

I have installed MYSQL  ODBC 8.0 and create a data source in ODBC data source administrator
[image: CON1]

But when I went to VS2015 and opened Crystal reporting and now want to add Data Source from ODBC(RDO) it pops up the Data Source selection window, but I did not find even a single source that I created.
[image: No Data Source name as empty as I said]

What am I doing wrong, please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal Reports Designer is 32-bit.  So you need to create the ODBC DSN as a 32-bit DSN.